# Salesforce lightning Fight with DOM and document.write()

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, dom

I am trying to duplicate the action created by the following code in the controller of a lightning component (aura). this is currently the code i have in place.

```
        let party = 'something';
        let OpenWindow = window.open();
        OpenWindow.document.write("<html><body>"+
        "<form name='goNow' action='"+actionURL+"' method='post'>"+
        "<input type='hidden' name='client' value='jimbo' />"+
        "<input type='hidden' name='Party' value='"+party+"' />"+
        "<input type='submit' value='Create Party/Link Party'>"+
        "</form> <SCRIPT>document.goNow.submit(); </SCRIPT></body></html>");
```

when i execute my button i get the following error:

```
$controller$submitDetails [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'write')]
```

if i remember right lightning cant use the DOM like that. Is there another way to do this? The goal is to submit some values to an external asp security page without adding them to the url.

please let me know if this is not enough information.
Thank you.

Comment: have you defined `actionUrl`?

Comment: yes the actionurl is a url to an asp page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the form in Aura:

```
<aura:attribute name="party" type="String" default="Some Value" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
<form aura:id="form" 
  action="{!v.actionURL}"
  target="_blank"
  method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="client" value="jimbo" />
  <input type="hidden" name="Party" value="{!v.party}" />
  <input type="submit" value="Create Party/Link Party" />
</form>
```

And in your controller:

```
({
   init: function(c,e,h) {
     c.find("form").getElement().submit();
   }
})
```

Or, you can even just submit a form via `fetch`, `XMLHttpRequest`, etc, just make sure to add the API endpoint to the [CSP](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.csp_trusted_sites.htm&type=5) in Setup | CSP Trusted Sites.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox, i am going to try this out right now!

Comment: unfortunately that didnt work. im getting the error $controller$submitDetails [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'submit')] thank you though i really appreciate you trying to help.

Comment: @JMLuttrell I forgot about getElement(). It's an extra step you need in Aura. Also, might be a lifecycle issue, actually. Try a setTimeout.

Comment: you know what, it is working. i had the form in an </aura:if> so that it wouldnt show up in my component and i guess it didnt like that. thank you again for all of your help.

Comment: @JMLuttrell Yes, aura:if literally removes the DOM elements. You can use `style="slds-hide"` if you want to make it invisible without removing from the DOM.

Comment: oh cool. i had just made a span and display:none around it but slds would probably be the more correct way to do it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the Lightning Locker Service.

Go [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console) and run your code (after you have defined `actionURL`).

If you turn on the Locker Service, your code will fail.

If you turn it off, it works.

If you really need this, you can set the API version of your component to 39, which will mean it won't be touched by the locker service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <AuraDefinitionBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>39.0</apiVersion>
    <description>My Component</description>
</AuraDefinitionBundle>
```

Or you can turn it off for everything in settings. **NOT** recommended.

Comment: Thanks Caspar. Its an all or nothing situation for this solution it seems. thats tough. im going to keep working on this. this is a pretty big security risk for us but thank you for the idea, i didnt know this existed.